# Cookie Not Being Created

Tags: php, setcookie

I have the following code:

```
setcookie('EmployeeLoggedIn', 1, time() + (86400 *30));
```

to set a cookie for one month. The result of this call is `true` and the response header shows:

> EmployeeLoggedIn=1; expires=Wed, 22-Jul-2020 13:04:35 GMT; Max-Age=2592000

The cookie doesn't exist on subsequent page loads though, the browser doesn't have the cookie stored, and `$_COOKIE` doesn't have the index. Am I running into the third state the manual describes:

> This does not indicate whether the user accepted the cookie.

There is no prompt in my browser to accept cookies, and there is no error stating the cookie was denied/blocked.

Comment: Are you reloading the exact same URL here, or are you checking for the cookie under a different one? You did not specify a path this cookie should be valid for, so it will be valid for the URL path it was set under only.

Comment: @CBroe  Thanks, misread the path part of doc I guess.